# BASH Wikitables get hardware info

Tags: linux, bash, mediawiki

Well I'm trying to make a simple script that will read a unix command and print this is a wikitable(class) output. So I can copy and paste the output to the wikipage. This is fun for getting hardware info and keeping track of our hardware. 
But the problem that I encounter is that some hardware have more than one ip address. I want to print each ipaddress in a new wikitable line. 
But so war no luck. Could some one help.

```
ipaddr=$(ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}')    

echo '{| class="wikitable"  
|+ Storage  
|-'  
printf -- '! %-19s !! %-14s !! %-20s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s\n' Hostname IP OS CPU Core RAM Name Type Size Used Mountpoint   
echo '|-'   
printf -- '| %-19s || %-14s\b || %-20s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s\n' "$HOSTNAME" "$ipaddr" "$os" "$cpu_model" "$cpu_cores" "$total_mem" "$disk_filesystem" "$disk_type" "$disk_size" "$disk_used" "$disk_mount"    
 echo '|}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way:

```
echo '{| class="wikitable"  
|+ Storage  
|-'  
printf -- '! %-19s !! %-14s !! %-20s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s !! %-14s\n' Hostname IP OS CPU Core RAM Name Type Size Used Mountpoint
echo '|-'   

# RELEVANT BIT HERE
for ipaddr in $(LC_ALL=C /sbin/ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'); do
    printf -- '| %-19s || %-14s\b || %-20s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s || %-14s\n' "$HOSTNAME" "$ipaddr" "$os" "$cpu_model" "$cpu_cores" "$total_mem" "$disk_filesystem" "$disk_type" "$disk_size" "$disk_used" "$disk_mount"    
done

echo '|}'
```

Since the output of the `ifconfig | foo | bar` command is a whitespace-delimited list -- that the whitespace is a newline doesn't matter -- of IP addresses, you can simply wade through them in a shell loop.

I took the liberty of forcing the locale for `ifconfig` to `C`, so that you'll not run into trouble on systems with a non-English locale. Without it, for example, I have `inet Adresse:127.0.0.1` instead of `inet addr:127.0.0.1`, which would confuse the later `grep` command.

If this is strictly for Linux, by the way, you may want to use `$(hostname -I)` instead of the whole `ifconfig` shebang to neatly sidestep the locale issue.